# Bulk update custom Sharepoint lists

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've searched multiple sources, watched coutless YouTube videos and I'm still no further forward.

I have multiple Access tables linked to Sharepoint lists. Each table / list has a unique identifier (which is a concatenation of 3 key fields (it's a long story!)). Anyways, with these unique fields I've created a custom list in Sharepoint to get a collective view of over 30 columns from various lists which I'd ideally like to perform a bulk update on.

To cut a long story short, I have over 1000 updates that need to be transferred from an Excel spreadsheet to the new custom (collective) SharePoint view. The fields are all mapped and are exactly the same layout within Excel, as to the new custom list.

The really frustrating thing with Sharepoint custom lists though is that you need to individually select each custom identifier in order to populate the rest of the row where lists are linked. I've tried to get around this however, just being met with greyed out fields that I'm unable to edit. (Unsure if this is because it's linked to Access, but tried everything to solve)

I have the unique identifier in Excel. I have all the columns mapped. Surely there must be a simple way to just copy the full Excell file and paste it into the custom Sharepoint view?!

Any help / alternative suggestions / drinks tokens appreciated.

Thanks in advance!